# nsIEditActionListener and addEditActionListener

Tags: firefox-addon, editor, selection, xpcom

I'm trying to understand this code:

```
315       let existingIndex = this._editors.indexOf(editableNode.editor);
316       if (existingIndex == -1) {
317         let x = this._editors.length;
318         this._editors[x] = editableNode.editor;
319         this._stateListeners[x] = this._createStateListener();
320         this._editors[x].addEditActionListener(this);
321         this._editors[x].addDocumentStateListener(this._stateListeners[x]);
322       }
```

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm#320

Especially `addEditActionListener(this);` what is `this`? MDN docs say it should be nsIEditActionListener but I can't find what this listener is comprised of MDN docs takes to broken page.

[nsIEditor - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIEditor?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=NsIEditor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is the Finder object; it implements the nsIEditActionListener interface (http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm#395)

That interface is defined here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/editor/idl/nsIEditActionListener.idl

So the code essentially attaches the Finder object to the editor, presumably so it can be notified of changes made in the editor at a later point.

Comment: Yes dude I posted the same first link above haha. Ahhhh the idl file is what I was looking for it has the functions the listener takes! Thanks man but my solution is not yet there, can you please help me understand how finder.jsm is addingListener `this`, I don't understand that.

Comment: My link should take you to a different line number but yes, it's in that same file.

Comment: Ah I see thanks Luckyrat! But when the finder.jsm does `this._editors[x].addEditActionListener(this);`. Super fantastic, from there I found the `_checkOverlap` and did ctrl+f and found that it is running this on [Line 478](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm#478) so really by adding this as editActionListener they are adding the whole Finder.jsm object huh? But because the Listener only knows WillDeleteNode and other functions listed in IDL it will ignore all the other function methods. I learned ton here thanks man!

Comment: With same technique I was able to figure out `nsIDocumentStateListener`, big thanks Lucky!